# How to pass a value from a Global Filter to the Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, filtering, global, global-filter

In a MVC3 app, I need a global filter to get a value and before any controller is executed, however how can I get later that value from a Controller?

```
public class MyGlobalFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        int i = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it's possible to set a new ViewBag value by the action controller context as the following code

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.MyNewValue = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx)

```
public class MyGlobalFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items["I"] = 10;
    }
}
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private int _i;
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _i = (int)HttpContext.Items["I"];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Just to make it clear, HttpContext.Current.Items is NOT session cache.  The data in this collection only lasts for the duration of the currently executing request.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  For more information, I found this link to be helpful:  [Difference between httpcontext.session and httpcontext.items](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/difference-between-httpcontext-current-items-and-httpcontext/)